# grab source of ajax web page

Tags: php, ajax, web

how is it possible to grab web page source from a ajax type web page:
curl doesn't seem to be able to get ajax generated source.

Sorry if duplicate, but looking throw questions didn't find answer.

Comment: sorry, page is visible after logging so can't show
ajax is used within a table where records are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If the page you want to grab uses ajax to compose different parts of it, then the content does not exist until all the loading is done.

You couldn't do this with curl, as curl acts as a client requesting only the URL you instruct it, but has no javascript engine to interpret the script and load other parts of the page.

If the content you are looking for is in one of the parts loaded through ajax, you should use the chrome inspector -> network tab and see what is the exact URL of the loaded page, then load that page using curl.

Comment: just checked chrome, network tab results can be seen following the link http://prohost.lt/images/stack.png
for 1 request i saw 10 such request, and the orderEntry is not what i should use